# How to efficiently sort a Multidimensional Arrray

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I was given a task to sort multidimensional array into ascending order without using the pre-made functions in the Array class (such as .sort).

I've tried asking some of my friends for ideas... Many of them turns the array into a single-dimensional array, sort it the way you would sort a single-dimensional array and then turns it back into a multidimensional array.

I'm just curious to know if there'd be any other ways to do this without having to go through such trouble.

Comment: What is the definition of "sorted" for a multi-dimensional array that you're basing this question on?

Comment: What do you mean by sorting the multidimensional array? Do you mean sorting the elements of individual sub-arrays?

Comment: See [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203530/4725875).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution... Thanks all

public static void sortAscending(int array[][]) {

```
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                for(int l = 0; l < array[k].length; l++) {
                    if(array[i][j] < array[k][l]) {
                        temp = array[i][j];
                        array[i][j] = array[k][l];
                        array[k][l] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a full exemple you can tri

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PartNumberQuantityDetailer {
// initialize a two dimensional array
static Integer[][] itemIdAndQty = new Integer[5][2];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize array values
    itemIdAndQty[0][0] = 1234;
    itemIdAndQty[0][1] = 46;
    itemIdAndQty[1][0] = 5443;
    itemIdAndQty[1][1] = 564;
    itemIdAndQty[2][0] = 362;
    itemIdAndQty[2][1] = 24;
    itemIdAndQty[3][0] = 6742;
    itemIdAndQty[3][1] = 825;
    itemIdAndQty[4][0] = 347;
    itemIdAndQty[4][1] = 549;
    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    // show the contents of array
    displayArray();
    // sort the array on item id(first column)
    Arrays.sort(itemIdAndQty, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
        @Override
                    //arguments to this method represent the arrays to be sorted   
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
                            //get the item ids which are at index 0 of the array
            Integer itemIdOne = o1[0];
            Integer itemIdTwo = o2[0];
            // sort on item id
            return itemIdOne.compareTo(itemIdTwo);
        }
    });
    // display array after sort
    System.out.println("After sorting on item id in ascending order");
    displayArray();
    // sort array on quantity(second column)
    Arrays.sort(itemIdAndQty, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
            Integer quantityOne = o1[1];
            Integer quantityTwo = o2[1];
            // reverse sort on quantity
            return quantityOne.compareTo(quantityTwo);
        }
    });
    // display array after sort
    System.out.println("After sorting on quantity in ascending order");
    displayArray();

}

private static void displayArray() {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Item id\t\tQuantity");
    for (int i = 0; i < itemIdAndQty.length; i++) {
        Integer[] itemRecord = itemIdAndQty[i];
        System.out.println(itemRecord[0] + "\t\t" + itemRecord[1]);
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
}
```

}]

Comment: The original post states in the very first sentence: `without using the pre-made functions in the Array class (such as .sort)`.

Answer (score 0):

**sort multidimensional array into ascending order:**

You can sort multi-d array row-wise or column -wise.

If you don't want to flatten the array that is convert it into 1-d then that mean you have to go through each row or column depending on your choice and apply quick-sort(better performance for small data set if pivot is chosen optimally) or merge-sort.

So you can do both in (considering avg. case) `O(nlogn)` and say there are n rown or n columns the time complexity will be `O(n^2(logn))`.

Now above the assumption is that you want to sort either row-wise or column-wise. 
If you want to achieve the both(row and column) then it's better if you convert the array to 1-d and then apply sort and then convert it back. Otherwise following above approach the time complexity can go `O(n^2(logn))` but in the other case it will be `O((n+m)log(n+m))` where `n` amd `m` are no. of rows and columns in array plus the `O(n+m)` space complexity.

In my opinion having a bit of space complexity so that you can bring down the run-time is preferable.